# ADC and DAC code for MSP430

Tags: adc, msp430, dac

I'm doing a DSP project using the MSP430. I want to take an analog signal and convert it to a digital output using a microcontroller attached to an ADC on a DSP board. How would I program this in C?

```
  Input  -->  Output
 Analog  --> Digital
Digital  -->  Analog
```

Comment: I dont think any one will code it for you =, but you may want to try the 43oh.com forums for code examples using the ADC on the msp430 line of chips.

Comment: Thanks for the site, i actually have found some useful information.

Answer (score 4):

This is the case where reading the datasheet is truly the best thing for you to do -- they will tell you exactly how to initialize, start [and stop], and use both an ADC and DAC. Since you haven't named a specific MSP430, ADC chip, or analog signal characteristics, I'm guessing that the design is very much in the initial planning stages. I suggest nailing down some requirements for each block in your system diagram, [looking for parts](http://focus.ti.com/en/multimedia/flash/selection_tools/mcu/mcu.html) that will do those things, then  reading their datasheets. Examples of requirements would be sampling rate/frequency (remember Nyquist) and depth (in bits, which can be translated from Volts); you can get an MSP430 with a 12-bit ADC and DAC on the chip. Something else is peripheral support: are you using a user interface? Comparators or trigger interrupt pins, used with hardware timers, are great for interfacing with and [debouncing](http://hackaday.com/2010/11/09/debounce-code-one-post-to-rule-them-all/) buttons; SPI, UART or I2C/TWI are serial protocols used to drive a screen. Note that there are a variety of ways to generate analog signals -- no need to limit searches to DAC peripherals or ICs: given some parameters, such as ripple and precision, you can determine what frequency and number of bits to use to do PWM with a single (or two) pins. You can also use a traditional R2R DAC, but make the LSB a PWM output to give you both R2R resistor calibration as well as additional precision.